# Is it possible to automatically write text in a React lexical editor using a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Im trying to write a chrome extension that automatically writes text in the text box when a user presses a button. Im pretty sure the website I am trying to make the chrome extension work on is using a lexical editor and react.

Does anyone know how I can input text into a lexical editor from its DOM element?

Ive tried sending Keypress events to the lexical editor element and changing its inner text without any luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316417/how-to-add-text-programmatically-with-lexical-editor